Some possible synonyms I've found
.net->c#
accounting->accounts
bech32-address->bech32
bip39->mnemonic
eu->europe
nxt-2.0->ardor
p2pubkey->p2pk
(Rename) raiblocks->nano
user-base->user-data
And, maybe removing virtual-currency, as it's what this website is about
confidential-transactions->zero-knowledge
Could you please make each of those synonyms if you agree with me about them being synonyms?


.net->c#

Never worked with either, but I thought that those were two not completely overlapping things.

accounting->accounts

The tag accounts refers to a specific feature of Bitcoin Core which finally is being removed. Accounting is about the process of keeping track of stuff. Gonna rename accounts to bitcoin-core-accounts.

bech32-address->bech32

Merged.

bip39->mnemonic

Merged into mnemonic-seed

eu->europe

Merged.

nxt-2.0->ardor

Merged

p2pubkey->p2pk

Done

(Rename) raiblocks->nano

Done

user-base->user-data

These two don't quite seem to match up. user-base is more about adoption, while user-data seems to be more about blockchain usage and storage footprint.

And, maybe removing virtual-currency, as it's what this website is about

Agreed, but I don't have time right now. I'll put it on my list of things to do. :)

confidential-transactions->zero-knowledge

While confidential transactions are an application of zero-knowledge proofs, they seem to have a mostly separate topic body on our site, so gonna leave that one be.

Could you please make each of those synonyms if you agree with me about them being synonyms?

Thanks for your report!

Update 2018-11-01: I've merged virtual-currency into currencies.
